# GeoIp-lite returning null

Tags: node.js, geoip

I have my replit project to get country by ip but lookup(ip) dont work [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs6la.jpg)
My code is

```js
app.get('/ip/locstion/get/', (req, res) => {

  const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

  const loc = lookup(ip);

 console.log(loc)

  console.log(ip)

  res.send("IP:" + ip+ "Location:\nCountry: "+loc.country + "Region: "+loc.region)

})
```

Comment: Are you sure `/ip/locstion/get/` is correct? Looks like a typo in `location` to me...

Comment: I know its showing ip in console when i go to locstion just see logs